# ¿Porque Required no funciona?

Tags: html5, required

Estoy creando un formulario de registro, algunos input tiene requiered pero al ejecutar el codigo y darle click a siguiente me pasa los campos vacios

Dejo el codigo:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">

<head>
  <title>Registro</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS3/estilo 5.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="conteiner">
      <section class="formulario-registro">
        <form action="Registro" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="get" novalidate target="_self">
          <label for="Registro">Registrarse</label>
          <h3>Nombre</h3>
          <input class="controltext" type="text" name="nombre" placeholder="Ingresa tu nombre" size="14" minlength="7" maxlength="16" autocomplete="name" list="nombres" required title="Ingresa tu nombre" pattern="\^[a-zA-Z]+ \s [a-zA-Z]+ $" spellcheck="true">
          <h3>Apellido</h3>
          <input class="controltext" type="text" name="apellido" placeholder="Ingresa tu apellido" size="14" minlength="7" maxlength="16" autocomplete="username" list="nombres" required title="Ingresa tu apellido" pattern="\^[a-zA-Z]+ \s [a-zA-Z]+ $" spellcheck="true">
          <h3>Fecha de nacimiento</h3>
          <input class="controltext" type="date" name="fecha" autocomplete="bday" list="fecha" step="01-01-2022" min="01-01-1940" max="31-12-2022">
          <h3>Edad</h3>
          <input class="controltext" type="number" name="edad" autocomplete="bday-year" list="edad" placeholder="edad" required title="edad" step="00" min="18" max="78">
          <input type="submit" value="Siguiente" id="Siguiente" class="Siguiente">
        </form>
      </section>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Elimina ```novalidate``` de tu etiqueta ```<form>``` y veras como te funcionara.

Answer (score 3):

Debes quitarle el atributo `novalidate` al elemento **`<form>`** porque está impidiendo esa comprobación.

Tal como dicen en su [documentación](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form#attr-novalidate):

> Este atributo booleano indica que el formulario no es validado cuando
> es enviado.